# Web-Scraping for Table Formate

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to copy the data from  TD and TR format. I am new in Data scraping so I did not find any results in google search.

I want to copy All Unit Size (example 5*5) in 'A' column, Regular
Price in 'B', Cash Price 'D', First 3 months 50% Off(offers) in 'F' and Reserve in 'G' column.

http://westgateselfstorage.com/index.php?page=estimator

Frankly saying, I'm not able to frame the code so it would be really helpful to me if someone helped me to build the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clipboard**

Do you care about layout? You can copy direct via clipboard and have same layout as page

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://westgateselfstorage.com/index.php?page=estimator", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    clipboard.SetText html.querySelector("#hiderow").outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

---

**QuerySelector and surrogate:**

If you do care more then we can use our usual method of finding the rows and looping, using a surrogate `HTMLDocument` variable to house html so we can leverage `querySelector` at a more granular level given we can't chain. The only difference here being that if we chuck html from `tr` level into `HTMLDocument` we need to add the `table` tags onto the html to ensure `querySelectorAll` can pick up the `td`s within the row i.e. the columns.

Now, I haven't split out old price from reduced price in the Cash Price column. If you need that just let me know. For now, I have left both.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, html2 As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://westgateselfstorage.com/index.php?page=estimator", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    html.body.innerHTML = html.querySelector("#hiderow").outerHTML

    Dim headers(), rows As Object, results(), columns As Object
    headers = Array("Size", "Reg price", vbNullString, "Cash price", vbNullString, "Offers", "Reserve")
    'grab the rows
    Set rows = html.querySelectorAll("tr")
    ReDim results(1 To rows.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    For i = 1 To rows.Length - 1 'skip headers row
        html2.body.innerHTML = "<table>" & rows.item(i).outerHTML & "</table>"
        Set columns = html2.querySelectorAll("td")
        results(i, 1) = columns.item(0).innerText
        results(i, 2) = columns.item(3).innerText
        results(i, 4) = columns.item(4).innerText
        results(i, 6) = columns.item(5).innerText
        results(i, 7) = "Reserve this unit"
    Next
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

---

**getElement(s)By*method* and chaining:**

We could also be more traditional and loop tr/td within a table as with getElement(s)By*method* allows us chaining to some extent (though I store in variables to make it easy to compare with the above)

Note:

```
rows(i).getElementsByTagName("td")
```

is basically chaining onto an individual element (row) within

```
Set rows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

e.g.

```
hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
```

All columns in first row via chaining.

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable, ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://westgateselfstorage.com/index.php?page=estimator", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set hTable = html.getElementById("hiderow")

    Dim headers(), rows As Object, results(), columns As Object
    headers = Array("Size", "Reg price", vbNullString, "Cash price", vbNullString, "Offers", "Reserve")
    'grab the rows
    Set rows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    ReDim results(1 To rows.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    For i = 1 To rows.Length - 1 'skip headers row
        Set columns = rows(i).getElementsByTagName("td")
        results(i, 1) = columns(0).innerText
        results(i, 2) = columns(3).innerText
        results(i, 4) = columns(4).innerText
        results(i, 6) = columns(5).innerText
        results(i, 7) = "Reserve this unit"
    Next
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python library pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd

tabs = pd.read_html('http://westgateselfstorage.com/index.php?page=estimator', header =0)
tabs[0].drop(tabs[0].columns[2], axis=1)
```

You may also want to drop column G since all rows there are identical.